# Validation on Devise on other controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Hi maybe this is a fool question, there are info in a lot of posts, but i do not understand because im learning rails..

I have made this controller,  posts_controller.rb

```
def index
    @posts = Post.all
end 

def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end


def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  @post.save
  redirect_to @post
end


def new
end

end
```

This is now public.. How can i make this just for admins, Im using devise. this is the controller for > SecureController

```
class SecureController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  authorize_resource

  def has_role?(current_user, role)
    return !!current_user.roles.find_by_name(role)
  end

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/403.html", :status => 403, :layout => false
  end

end
```

Also Registratons controller

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    if current_user.user_type == 'player'
      player_steps_path
    elsif current_user.user_type == 'coach'
      coach_steps_path
    elsif current_user.user_type == 'elite'
      candidates_path
    end
  end
end
```

How can i make that domain.com/posts/new is just available for Admin, but domain.com/posts is open to everyone..

Also i see there is views for admin... how can i make domain.com/admin/posts/new to work?

Any Documentation will be nice, but also a explanation, cause as i said, im just learning rails.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:except`

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:new]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, where do i have to set that line.. in the posts_controller inside the def, or before all of them.. how does this works, need to understand.

Comment: Yes, that's right, just like you did with your secure_controller.  before_filter works a pre-condition validator, for instance, when user calls the show action, your posts controller will first call the authenticate_user! to see if the user is signed in. before_filter takes in a few options to conditionally verify a certain action. Check out the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/before_filter) for more information

Comment: there was a typo (had : on before_filter instead of authenticate_user)

Comment: sorry i found it, thanks.. it was not your line anyway sorry i didnt check the error right first